# Python WMI Network Adapter Configuration parameter issue [Windows 8.1] [Python 2.7] [WMI 1.4.9]

Tags: python, wmi

When I try to do this

```
SetDynamicDNSRegistration(True)
```

It returns '68' which I have looked up on the [MSDN WMI page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393298(v=vs.85).aspx) and it means "Invalid Input Parameter".

**Full Script**

```
import wmi

nic_configs = wmi.WMI('').Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]

# IP address, subnetmask and gateway values should be unicode objects
ip = u'192.168.0.151'
subnetmask = u'255.255.255.0'
gateway = u'192.168.0.1'
dns = u'192.168.0.1'

# Set IP address, subnetmask and default gateway
# Note: EnableStatic() and SetGateways() methods require *lists* of values to be passed
a = nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
b = nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
c = nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder([dns])
d = nic.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(True)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

What is wrong? I'm sure "True" is the right Python syntax for the boolean TRUE... I don't even know anymore...

Comment: What happens if you try `nic.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(FullDNSRegistrationEnabled=1)`?

Comment: Perfect but I can hardly mark a comment as an accepted answer... Do you mind wording it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a Python boolean, use its corresponding boolean integer. So instead of

```
nic.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(True)
```

use

```
nic.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(FullDNSRegistrationEnabled=1)
```